# Why did Madame Jocasta Nu leave the Jedi Council?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, character-motivation, attack-of-the-clones

According to [this article on StarWars.com](https://www.starwars.com/news/the-jedi-council-meet-the-masters), Madame [Jocasta Nu](https://www.starwars.com/databank/jocasta-nu) - Chief Librarian of the Jedi Archives, played by [Alethea McGrath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alethea_McGrath) in *Attack of the Clones* (rest in peace) - was once part of the Jedi Council:

> There had been a time when Chief Librarian Jocasta Nu had her seat on
>   the Council as did Sifo-Dyas before he mysteriously vanished on
>   Felucia.

This is the first time I've heard of this, and that article is the only source I can find for it.

[Jocasta Nu's Wookieepedia entry](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jocasta_Nu) doesn't make mention of it, although it does seem to indicate that she was fairly instrumental to the Council after the Attack of the Clones and somewhat close to them.

**Just how influential a member of the Jedi Council was Jocasta Nu when she was part of it, and is there a reason she left that seat on the Council - arguably the second-most senior role possible for a Jedi - to become a glorified archivist?**

Comment: My best guess would be that being the Chief Librarian and being on the Jedi council are exclusive positions, but I cannot find any proof. Also, don’t forget that the Jedi aspire to self-sacrifice and asceticism. They would see nothing wrong, most likely, with abandoning a senior position to serve the Order better. Don’t forget that the Order’s Grand Master lived in a swamp for about two decades.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The official novelisation for *Attack of the Clones* gives the impression that about five years before the events of *The Phantom Menace* there was an almighty brouhaha in the Jedi Council. The upshot was that the moderates won the day and, as a result, Sifo-Dyas was forced to step down, Qui-Gon Jinn was refused a seat despite his obvious credentials and Count Dooku left the order entirely over much the same issue, that the Jedi Order was serving a corrupt Republic.

Some time before this period, Nu (who apparently had sympathies for all three of these individuals and their argument) left the Council so that she could work as Chief Archivist, a role that seems to be little more than a sinecure.

No specific reason is given for her depature, but it would appear that those with strongly held views about opposing, or at least restraining the excesses of a failing Republic have been systematically moved into less powerful positions while those who support the status quo have risen in power.

> ***“Well, one might say he*** [Dooku] ***was a bit out of step with the decisions of
>   the Council,” the Archivist replied. “Much like your old Master,
>   Qui-Gon.”***
>
> ...
>
> *“Really?” Obi-Wan prompted, wanting the information about Dooku, of
>   course, but also hoping to garner some insight into his old and
>   beloved Master.*
>
> *“Oh, yes, they were alike in many ways. Very individual thinkers.
>   Idealists.” She stared at the bust intently, and it seemed to Obi-Wan
>   as if she had suddenly gone far, far away. “He was always striving to
>   become a more powerful Jedi. He wanted to be the best. With a
>   lightsaber, in the old style of fencing, he had no match. His
>   knowledge of the Force was… unique. **In the end, I think he left
>   because he lost faith in the Republic. He believed that politics were
>   corrupt…”***
>
> ***Jocasta Nu paused for a moment and looked at Obi-Wan, a very revealing
>   expression that showed she did not think Dooku as out of step as many
>   of the others apparently did.***
>
> ***“And he felt that the Jedi betrayed themselves by serving the
>   politicians,”*** the Archivist stated.
>
> *Obi-Wan blinked, soaking in the words. **He knew that many, Qui-Gon
>   included-even himself included, at times-often felt the same way.***
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Attack of the Clones - Official Novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_II:_Attack_of_the_Clones_(novel))</sup></sub>